# Metro UI Css - Posicionamiento de barra de navegacion con menu lateral visible

Tags: html, css

Estoy probando el framework Metro UI CSS para hacer la maqueta de una aplicación y estoy teniendo un problema con el posicionamiento de la barra de navegación.

- **Documentación:** https://metroui.org.ua/intro.html
- **Ejemplo:** https://jsfiddle.net/prkc0mfL/

En el ejemplo que os adjunto, cuando se pulsa el botón del menú en pantallas pequeñas, la capa de la aplicación se desplaza hacia la derecha (barra de navegación y contenido) y deja ver a la izquierda la capa donde irá ubicado el menú. El problema es que para páginas largas, la barra de navegación sube con la pagina al hacer scroll.

Necesito que se conserve el desplazamiento lateral de la capa de la aplicación, al igual que hace actualmente, pero que la barra de navegación quede fija al hacer scroll.

He revisado la documentación del framework y no consigo encontrar la combinación de clases que necesito para realizar esto. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? He probado con casi todas las combinaciones de posiciones y no consigo hacerlo.

Espero me podáis decir donde esta mi error.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era mas simple de lo que pensaba, bastaba con añadir `style="overflow-y: auto"` en la linea 33 y con eso se solucionaba

https://jsfiddle.net/fs6qkt9b/

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código como texto tanto en tu pregunta como en tu respuesta